# How to read lists within csv files using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, dataset

So, I have a problem with lists inside a csv file, then I went searching for the resolution, and i have found this:
https://github.com/MaxHilsdorf/dealing_with_lists_in_pandas/blob/master/list_values_in_pandas.ipynb
Its pretty good, but for some reason its not working for me, let me show the code:

```
import pandas as pd
fruits = pd.read_csv('D:/Dados Usuario/Área de Trabalho/_python/machine_learning/favorite_fruits.csv', low_memory=True,usecols= ["name","age","favorite_fruits"])
#nome = fruits["name"]
#idade = fruits["age"]
frutas = fruits["favorite_fruits"]
print(frutas)

  favorite_fruits
0            ['1'
1        ['apple'
2              []
3       ['banana'
4   ['strawberry'
5    ['blueberry'
6        ['mango'
7   ['watermelon'
8         ['pear'
9        ['peach'
```

The question is:
Why its reading only the first cell of each list?

Here is the dataset:
https://github.com/MaxHilsdorf/dealing_with_lists_in_pandas/blob/master/fruits.csv

I couldnt read anything the way it was, so in mine dataset I took of the "" from each list, and only left '' for each cell on the list, then i could read the first cell.
I also had to add  low_memory=True,usecols= ["name","age","favorite_fruits"] for that.
The other columns work just fine, its just this one with the lists that are not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to use standard pandas and python

- `read_csv()` to load the file
- `apply(json.loads)` to convert from a string to an actual list
- if you want rows for each fruit `explode()`

#### convert strings to lists

```
import requests, json, io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MaxHilsdorf/dealing_with_lists_in_pandas/master/fruits.csv").text), sep=";")
df = df.assign(favorite_fruits=df["favorite_fruits"].apply(json.loads))
```

|  | name | age | favorite_fruits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | tammy | 6 | ['banana', 'mango', 'orange', 'watermelon'] |
| 1 | bonny | 8 | ['apple', 'pear', 'peach'] |
| 2 | helga | 8 | [] |
| 3 | tom | 10 | ['banana', 'maracuja', 'watermelon', 'apple', 'pineapple'] |
| 4 | jerome | 7 | ['strawberry', 'raspberry', 'blueberry'] |
| 5 | hans | 9 | ['blueberry', 'watermelon', 'apple', 'raspberry'] |
| 6 | lisa | 10 | ['mango', 'pineapple', 'orange'] |
| 7 | trish | 6 | ['watermelon', 'apple', 'blueberry', 'pear', 'strawberry'] |
| 8 | steve | 8 | ['pear', 'strawberry', 'raspberry'] |
| 9 | antoine | 5 | ['peach', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'blueberry'] |

#### convert and explode

```
import requests, json
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MaxHilsdorf/dealing_with_lists_in_pandas/master/fruits.csv").text), sep=";")
df.join(df["favorite_fruits"].apply(json.loads).explode(), rsuffix="_val")
```

#### sample output

|  | name | age | favorite_fruits | favorite_fruits_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | tammy | 6 | ["banana", "mango", "orange", "watermelon"] | banana |
| 0 | tammy | 6 | ["banana", "mango", "orange", "watermelon"] | mango |
| 0 | tammy | 6 | ["banana", "mango", "orange", "watermelon"] | orange |
| 0 | tammy | 6 | ["banana", "mango", "orange", "watermelon"] | watermelon |
| 1 | bonny | 8 | ["apple", "pear", "peach"] | apple |
| 1 | bonny | 8 | ["apple", "pear", "peach"] | pear |
| 1 | bonny | 8 | ["apple", "pear", "peach"] | peach |
| 2 | helga | 8 | [] | nan |
| 3 | tom | 10 | ["banana", "maracuja", "watermelon", "apple", "pineapple"] | banana |
| 3 | tom | 10 | ["banana", "maracuja", "watermelon", "apple", "pineapple"] | maracuja |

Comment: It doesnt work, i just get tons of errors with your solution.
I must be forgetting something, it should work, everything else works.
And if I dont put low_memory=True,usecols= ["name","age","favorite_fruits"] I also get tons of errors.
I dont need a row for each fruit, I just wanna read the csv with the lists, and print the lists.

Comment: your sample data is on GitHub and he code I've provided reads it directly from GitHub.  `df["favorite_fruits"].apply(json.loads)` will change string representation into a list. are you using a very out of date version of pandas? `pd.__version__`

Comment: No, i recently installed Pandas, so its updated. Im using PyCharm as IDE,and i've downloaded the sample data into my notebook.
`df["favorite_fruits"].apply(json.loads)` gets only a bunch of errors.( When I dont use it, it gets only the first cell and I'm back to start)
If you're willing, I would apreciatte your email, then I could explain properly.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  PyCharm does not include pandas.  I install using `pip` in a virtual env.  Typically PyCharm will create a virtual env for your project.  I suspect you have not correctly downloaded file,  when you run code exactly as I have written that gets data from https request does it fail?  i.e. don't use your manually downloaded data

Comment: I didnt tried getting the data from the https, I'm only doing this because I have another dataset with about 11.000 lines, that will be running from my computer. I'm testing with his data because its small and simple, but it has to be downloaded.